# How many triangles are see in complete K5 graph

Tags: graph-theory, binomial-coefficients, triangles

How many triangles are on picture below?

On yahoo answers I have found that numbers of triangles in complete graph with n nodes is: $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$

But how this formula has been estimated?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any set of three vertices forms exactly one unique triangle. How many of these sets exists? We can use the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!}=\frac {n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)}{6}$

Comment: Why $\binom{n}{3}$? n is number of nodes, 3 is number of verticles which creates triangle but what is the connection?

Comment: If I tell you three vertices on the graph then there is a unique triangle which connects all three of those vertices, thus the number of triangles is equal to the number of 3-sets of the vertex set of the graph. That vertex set has size $n$ and therefore it has $\binom{n}{3}$ 3-sets.

Comment: As I understand, OP wants to know the number of all triangles that apear not only created with the nodes.

Comment: Well the answer got accepted @Aqua